# Android - multiple finger touches for 1 button

Tags: android, touch-event, buttonclick

I want a button that can detect multiple fingers. Like ı am holding with 1 finger and then 1 more finger touches that button it has to detect that.

Or
a button that when pushed, automatically release that button dont care if it actually released or not.

I use onTouchevent for multiple buttons for my drum kit project.

```
        @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        Animation zoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.zoomin);
        switch (motionEvent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                switch(view.getId())
                {

                    case R.id.BassL:
                        findViewById(R.id.bass).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.play(BassD,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.BassR:
                        findViewById(R.id.bass).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.play(BassD,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.SnareL:
                        findViewById(R.id.snare).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.play(SnareD,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.SnareR:
                        findViewById(R.id.snare).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.play(SnareD,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.OpenHihat:
                        findViewById(R.id.hihat).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.stop(OpenH);
                        sp.play(OpenH,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.CloseHihat:
                        findViewById(R.id.hihat).startAnimation(zoomIn);

                        sp.play(CloseH,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.RideSurface:
                        findViewById(R.id.ride).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.stop(RideS);
                        sp.play(RideS,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                    case R.id.RideTop:
                        findViewById(R.id.ride).startAnimation(zoomIn);
                        sp.play(RideT,1.0f,1.0f,0,0,1.0f);
                        break;
                }



        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the pointer id associated to the MotionEvent you've just received.

See the docs for more info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId(int)